# Matplotlib groupby scatter colormap Warning: " No data for colormapping provided via 'c' "

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I'm having issues with colormapping of simple scatter plots when created using pandas `groupby`.

#### Example

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'class': ['A']*5 + ['B']*5,
                         'index': [i for i in range(10)],
                         'data': [i for i in range(5)] + [i+1 for i in range(5)]})
# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, grp in df.groupby('class'):
    grp.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='index', y='data', label=key)
```

#### The Warning I get

> /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py:1114: UserWarning: No data for colormapping provided via 'c'. Parameters 'cmap' will be ignored
> scatter = ax.scatter(

#### The Output plot

The scatter plot is produced, but matplotlib uses the same color for both classes.

[image]

If I use `df.plot()` instead of `df.plot.scatter()` the warning is not printed, and the plot shows as expected, with different colors for the two classes. So it seems to be an issue with `scatter`.
What am I doing wrong?

#### Package versions:

```
pandas:      1.4.3
matplotlib:  3.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

For scatterplot, the color of points is defined by the additional parameter `c`, which in your case is the same, i.e. `None` for both calls to plot each scatterplot.

You need to define `c` to be different in both calls, so how about giving it some random color?

```
from random import randint

# Plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key, grp in df.groupby('class'):
    random_color="#" + f"{randint(0, 0xFFFFFF):06x}"
    grp.plot.scatter(ax=ax, x='index', y='data', label=key,
                     c=random_color,
                    )
```

Regards.